# What will happen to my Ubuntu/Windows set up upon upgrade to Windows 10?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

Microsoft is offering free upgrades to Windows 10 for certain users. Currently I am running a Ubuntu/ Windows 8.1 dual boot set up on my laptop.

I rarely boot into Windows but just to keep up to date with what is going on there I would like to keep it. What can I expect when opting to upgrade to Windows 10? My suspicion is that the least it will do is make sure there is the Windows boot loader installed and there is only one option to boot.

With Win 10 being released today I wonder if anyone has gone through the upgrade path and would like to share his findings? What can I expect to happen?

Comment: You might get a better answer on a Windows SE or in Super User SE -- people have been testing Win10 for several months, almost certainly some of those have dual boot with Ubuntu.

Comment: Looks like w10 is more a cosmetic update and has not got changes at the boot level. To me looks like it should be fine :)

Answer (score -1):

I can't see what can affect Ubuntu even if it's installed with wubi by upgrading windows.
Even if your grub is overwritten by the windows bootloader you can easily restore it with [boot-repair](http://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/boot-repair).

Comment: You can not install W8 with WUBI.

Comment: I was asking for experiences with the actual official release and upgrade to the final Version being rolled out as of today.

Comment: @Rinzwind i meant that even if he used wubi to install Ubuntu with windows 8 he shouldnt have issues

Comment: The user needs to know if it's safe to upgrade to Windows 10, or will it destroy his Ubuntu installation and files. (I also want to know the answer. Older versions of Windows used to reformat the entire drive.) This doesn't answer the question.